# Common import's order for IntelliJ and Eclipse using google-java-format

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, google-java-format

In our team we're using IntelliJ and Eclipse. As formatter we're plugins for Eclipse and IntelliJ from v1.18.1 of https://github.com/google/google-java-format

We set the same imports layouts for both IDEs:

[Eclipse import layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwzzr.png)

[IntelliJ import layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2kmL.png)

There are differences in imports order:

Imports in IntelliJ:

```
import com.domain.sap.IF.helper.DocumentHelper;
import com.domain.sap.SapUtility;
import com.domain.sap.SyncDocument;
```

Imports in Eclipse:

```
import com.domain.sap.SapUtility;
import com.domain.sap.SyncDocument;
import com.domain.sap.IF.helper.DocumentHelper;
```

For me it looks like IntelliJ uses a Code Formatter also for Imports formatting and Eclipse uses it's own mechanism.
How to make it common?

Comment: In Eclipse, make sure _Organize imports_ is not enabled as a so-called _Save Action_: _Project > Properties: Java Editor > Save Actions_.

Comment: The order Eclipse uses if Organize Imports is used is defined in the Preferences in Java > Code Style > Organize Imports.

Comment: *Organize Import* option is disabled. To clarify: I'm talking that import goes with wrong order when I'm doing Shift + Ctrl + O

Comment: _Organize Import_ is something different than formatting. When you format the file, does the Google Java formatter change the order of the imports? If yes and if it is the order you want, then does enabling formatting as _Save Action_ solve your problem?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + O for IntelliJ changes order of imports according to the Google Java Style -> OK.
Shift + Ctrl + O for Eclipse changes order of imports, but it's different than in IntelliJ. Looks like chosen formatter in Eclipse has no effect in terms of imports order. Order stays the same. no matter which formatter is set in Eclipse.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I asked whether _Format_ (Ctrl+Shift+F) has an effect on the order in Eclipse.

Comment: No, *Format* in Eclipse has no effect on the order of imports.

Comment: But the Google formatter should change the order. Make sure the Google formatter is used in the project: _Project > Properties: Java Code Style > Formatter_.

Comment: Yes, it's set. What I've found is that Google formatter is not used for Import reordering/optimization in Eclipse. That's an Eclipse specification. Imports are sorted by an Eclipse settings. IntelliJ is using Google formatter to reorder imports and sorts them according to the ASCII table, but Eclipse isn't. That's why capital letters go first in IntelliJ.

Comment: I see that you have reported it here: https://github.com/google/google-java-format/issues/1007 (which might be a duplicate of [this](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/issues/289)).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file on the project. IntelliJ has native support and Eclipse requires a [plugin](https://github.com/ncjones/editorconfig-eclipse#readme).

It will allow to set a lot of import related configurations like

```
ij_java_imports_layout = *,|,javax.**,java.**,|,$*
```

Comment: That allows to set  a package order by a domain. My problem is that IntelliJ uses an ASCII table for imports sorting and Eclipse sort by non-ASCII.